# Wi-Fi hotspot with access of device storage

Tags: storage, networking, wifi-hotspot

Is it possible to create Wi-Fi **hotspot** on Android phone with **access of device storage** through that network?

I'm able to create hotspot OR share storage through network, but is it possible to do it together at same time, with just one device?

Comment: How are you sharing access to device storage? You can use some server app to host an http/ftp/webdav etc., servers and bind them to a network interface if needed be. Is this not what you want btw?

Comment: @Firelord these apps what i tried need connection through Wi-Fi to share storage. My question is how to connect them to the hotspot from same device (no another Wi-Fi)

Comment: @Francis hotspot is the Wi-Fi. Other than some technical differences, a device should not differentiate between a hotspot and a Wi-Fi router. All that you need is the IP address to access a device on network. It makes no difference if the IP is static or is assigned by WiFi router or hotspot. Though some app might have unnecessary limitation of WiFi requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not quite clear and I assume that you wanted to turn on Hotspot on your first device and connect to the Hotspot on your second device and access the Internal Storage of the first device.

What you could try is by using a File Manager app called "FX File Manager: The file manager with privacy" and it is available for download in the Google Play Store

Step 1:
Open up FX and navigate to the Web Access feature.
[image]

Step 2:
Turn on your Wi-Fi Hotspot

Step 3:
Turn on Web Access by pressing on the "Power On" button
[image]

Step 4:
A web "link" and a password will be displayed and you will need to type in this "link" on the second device (make sure you are connected to the first device's hotspot on your second device)

Step 5:
Enter the "link" displayed in Web Access and enter the password if prompted.

There you have it, you should have access to your first device's storage!